# Is it possible to map static IP Addresses to consistent ports on a switch?

Tags: linux, windows, networking

First, a little background: I am in a situation where I need to image blank hard drives in hundreds of computers.  We do this by connecting the systems to an ethernet switch and having them boot over ethernet, loading a small Linux image which does some system diagnostics, determines the UUID of the motherboard, partitions the disk etc and then loads a predetermined Windows Image.  I want to be able to associate this UUID with a serial number that I generate and store it in a database, and then we will print a label with the serial number and put it on the computer.  **The problem** is, I want it to be able to easily put the correct label on the corresponding system in order to minimize human error and prevent systems being mixed up.  In order to simplify this, I need to be able to identify the physical location of the system based on some information in software, e.g. IP address, mac address or the likes so I can show the person physically handling these systems which serial number belongs to, e.g., the top-left computer.  We have a pretty nice switch, a Cisco sg300-52, so I'm thinking there has to be some way to achieve this correlation, but my knowledge is lacking in this department.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The title of your question is very misleading.
You are looking to correlate some network information (MAC) to the physical port (and by deduction the location of the PC).

This is easy: Each switch keeps a mac-address-table by which it tracks on which port a given mac-address was last seen.
Most switches can show you this table, either in their web-interface or by using a command on the command line.
As you already have the MAC you can simply look a that table to find the switchport and from there deduce the location on the installation table or rack.

You biggest problem is finding a way to read that table in an easy to use way so you can automate the process as much as possible. I can't help you there. I'm not familiar with this particular model of switch.
(They are branded Cisco but in reality they are Linksys (Cisco owned Linksys for a while) devices. They are not as full featured as real Cisco switches, but should still be able to somehow show you the mac-address table.)

Comment: Apologies for the misleading title, this is what I was looking for thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Switch ports? No. (Not unless all of your switches are 'smart' enough to mangle the port ID into all DHCP requests that pass through...)

MAC addresses? Sure. Pretty much **any** DHCP server – even the tiny ones in home routers – will have a "static lease" function for assigning IP addresses to specific MACs. In the ISC DHCPd configuration it would look like this:

```
host rain {
    hardware ethernet f4:6d:04:85:fc:d7;
    fixed-address 293.319.181.194;
}
```

Comment: Hmm so this would automatically assign an IP address to a device with a given MAC address, if I understand correctly? The problem is we're constantly connecting new systems, and want to be able to associate the MAC/IP/any system identifier with the actual physical port somehow